# Mounting nfs on populated folder: is it dangerous?

Tags: mount, nfs

**Context:** i have a NFS client and a NFS server. The NFS client has a folder named /usr/local/myfolder and it has some files that are too heavy to be constantly moved around.

I want to mount my nfs server in the client by writing:

```
10.10.10.13:/server/folder /usr/local/myfolder nfs defaults 0 0
```

Lets say /server/folder is populated with files serv1 and serv2. /usr/local/myfolder is populated with cli1 and cli2.

I noticed that when i do

```
sudo mount -av
```

inside the client, cli1 and cli2 vanish and only serv1 and serv2 are visible. When i do

```
sudo umount /usr/local/myfolder
```

serv1 and serv2 vanish again and cli1 and cli2 are back.

**The question is:** by mounting the nfs server in a client populated folder, can i rest assured that the local files will always come back when i umount? Or is it possible that the disk understands that the space where local files are written is now available and might overwrite the local files?

In other words: are my local files safe?

Comment: Just try. Doing test is always better then assumptions. In any case no: nobody should cancel your file without being explicitly told to do so. The files remains. Just it may cause surprise in case of bugs/problem on filesystem (you may not notice that system unmounted your filesystem because some problems (e.g. network, or it never mounted because initialization failed). So be careful (and in any case you have the backups, as all people)

Comment: Thanks! I am trying indeed and for now i did not notice any surprise behavior, but i didnt know where to search for this information to be sure.